# How to restrict storyboard to begin automatically in Windows 8 store app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, storyboard, winrt-xaml

I am using two storyboards to move balls(image) left and right directions, on tap event of left button I want to move balls in left direction and on tap event of right button , balls should move in right direction. It's working correctly on taping left and right button, but on loading application storyboards begins automatically and balls move one step without tapping buttons. How do I restrict storyboard to begin automatically?

This is my first storyboard to move balls 40 pixels in left direction:

```
<EventTrigger>
<BeginStoryboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="ballstoryleft">
<DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="balltrans" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX"
Duration="0:0:0.5" By="-40" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
<DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
<ElasticEase Oscillations="0" Springiness="1" />
</DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
</DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

This is my second storyboard to move balls 40 pixels in right direction:

```
<EventTrigger>
<BeginStoryboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="ballstoryright">
<DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="balltrans" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX"
         Duration="0:0:0.5" By="40"    FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
<DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
<ElasticEase Oscillations="0" Springiness="1" />
</DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
</DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

I have written this code in code behind:

```
private void imgleft_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
ballstoryleft.Begin();
}
private void imgright_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
ballstoryright.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you put your `Storyboards`? I see they are inside `EventTriggers`. They might be the ones triggering the storyboards when the application loads.

You should just put both `Storyboards` in a `Resources` collection:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ballstoryleft">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="balltrans" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX" 
                         Duration="0:0:0.5" By="-40" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ElasticEase Oscillations="0" Springiness="1" />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ballstoryright">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="balltrans" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX" 
                         Duration="0:0:0.5" By="40" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ElasticEase Oscillations="0" Springiness="1" />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

Now there should be no reason for them to trigger automatically while your code which triggers them on tap should still work just like it does now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define whole story board from code behind also

Try this example:

```
void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) 
{ 
  DoubleAnimation anima = new DoubleAnimation
   { 
     EnableDependentAnimation = true,
     To = 96, 
     Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)), 
     AutoReverse = true, 
     RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(3) };
     Storyboard.SetTarget(anima, sender as Button);
     Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anima, "FontSize");
     Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
     storyboard.Children.Add(anima); 
     storyboard.Begin();
  }
```